# Faster selects on large table with shredded/flattened xml field

Tags: sql-server, xml, select, query-performance

Given a MS SQL EXPRESS 2008 R2 Table with records such as below

```
ArchiveId   ScheduleId  Data
391063      62          <Data>....</Data>
391064      62          <Data>....</Data>
391065      63          <Data>....</Data>
```

Where XML in Data Field is structured like this

```
<Data>
  <Value>1.0</Value>
  <Value>2.0</Value>
  <Value>3.0</Value>
  <Value>4.0</Value>
</Data>
```

What is the fastest way to do a select with the following catches

- query will need to return upwards of 2M+ rows!
- be returned by ScheduleId
- return the "data" column `Value` nodes shredded into columns
- and include the id fields archiveid and scheduleid for each row returned
- The number of "Value" elements is variable per ScheduleId but always the same for a given ScheduleId
- there are only ever `<Value>` nodes within the `<Data>` node and they are always numbers
- table can have upwards of 50M rows and is currently only indexed on ScheduleId(Non-Unique Non-Clustered) and ArchiveId(PK Clustered)

Ideally I'm Looking for data of the format;

```
ArchiveId   ScheduleId  Value1  Value2  etc
391063      62          1.0     2.0
391064      62          1.1     2.1
```

I have tried to use

```
select 
    ArchiveId, 
    ScheduleId , 
    v.value('(Value/text())[1]', 'float') as value1 , 
    v.value('(Value/text())[2]', 'float') as value2 , 
    v.value('(Value/text())[3]', 'float') as value3 , 
    v.value('(Value/text())[4]', 'float') as value4  
from 
    Archives 
    cross apply [data].nodes('//Data') x(v) 
where 
    ScheduleId = 2499
```

and straight .values() and .queries()

```
select 
    ArchiveId,
    ScheduleId,
    Data.value('(/Data/Value/text())[1]', 'float') as value1,
    Data.value('(/Data/Value/text())[2]', 'float') as value2,
    Data.value('(/Data/Value/text())[3]', 'float') as value3,
    Data.value('(/Data/Value/text())[4]', 'float') as value4
from 
    Archives 
where 
    ScheduleId = 2499
order by 
    ArchiveId asc
```

Both work but are really slow on large datasets and i was wondering if there is a quicker way to do this sort of thing on very large numbers of rows. I realise that no matter what it will take a while but what are my best bets when doing this.

Numerous examples here but they all have more complex or dynamic data structures or have some kind of complex selection requirements based on the xml content itself.

The data i have is always the same structure (one data node and x value nodes) and the selection criteria **is not** in the xml at all.

Im just looking for the simplest way to pull ALOT of records back while flattening the xml to columns.

**EDIT:** Essentially we store graphing data in the xml to later plot a line graph. Importantly, whilst the number of  elements for the same ScheduleId will always be the same, different ScheduleId's will have a different number of value elements.e.g.

- All ScheduleId=1 have 3 value elements (time_X, var1_Y, var2_Y)
- All ScheduleId=2 have 2 value elements (time_X, var1_Y)
- All ScheduleId=3 have 33 value elements (time_X, var1_Y,......)
  etc

Comment: If you want maximum performance you need to eliminate the XML in the database and just use columns on the main table or a child table.

Comment: i wish i could but this is what i have to work with, so im just looking for the best of a bad situation type solution.

Comment: You can try removing the float conversion to see if that helps. You can create indexes on the XML "columns" but this will grow your DB quite a bit.

Comment: Tried adding an index but db grew to sql express limit of 10gb and stopped.

the .Value requires a second parameter so not sure how to remove the cast...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What might be the best solution is to allow your system to add the data with the XML column into the Archive table as it is, but then move the data over on a schedule to a normalized table structure for reporting.  You could either set up a SQL Agent Job or create some service program to move or copy the data to your reporting database.  Once the data is in your reporting tables, you could either:

- Purge the records from the Archive table
- Move Archive table records to another table/database with the same structure.
- Create a field that flags when the record has been added to the report table/database.

You could choose whichever one would meet your requirements.

Your reporting tables would basically be split into two or three tables.  There's the `ArchiveTable` made of (**`ArchiveId`**, ScheduleId).  Then you have your `ArchiveDataPointTable` made of (**`ArchiveId`**, **`ValueId`**, `DataPointValue`).  You could also create a `ValuesTable` of (**`ValueId`**, `ValueDescription`) if you wanted labels for your data points.  Then your chart reports could run off a pivot queries with only the data points that you need.  Because there would be no string parsing, and all the values are numeric, it should be very fast.

Comment: Ultimatly im going to use a variation of this solution and flatten the table into regular columns, all queries etc just run that much faster. Its pretty much heart surgery stuff for the application but in the long run it will speed things up considerably even if it does end up storing extra empty columns.

Answer (score 3):

If you can add fields to the `Archives` table, you could create persisted calculated fields as functions of the XML data.  So for example you create a field `value1` and set it to equal `Data.value('(/Data/Value/text())[1]', 'float')` and then set the persisted flag on the column.  This way it will be parsed once when the record is added or updated and then it has it's own data field that you can select for output.

It's a bit clunky to put into practice though because you have to use a udf because you can't use the XML methods directly.  But it looks something like this:

```
GO
create table TempArchive
(
  ArchiveId integer not null,
  ScheduleId integer not null,
  [Data] xml not null,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Archive
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ArchiveId)
  WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)
GO
create function udf_getdatacolumn
(
    @data xml,
    @index as int
) RETURNS float
with schemabinding
as
begin
return @data.value('(/Data/Value/text())[sql:variable("@index")][1]', 'float')
end
GO
alter table TempArchive add value1 as (dbo.udf_getdatacolumn(data, 1)) persisted
alter table TempArchive add value2 as (dbo.udf_getdatacolumn(data, 2)) persisted
alter table TempArchive add value3 as (dbo.udf_getdatacolumn(data, 3)) persisted
alter table TempArchive add value4 as (dbo.udf_getdatacolumn(data, 4)) persisted
GO
insert into TempArchive values (1, 2, '<Data>
  <Value>1.0</Value>
  <Value>2.0</Value>
  <Value>3.0</Value>
  <Value>4.0</Value>
</Data>')
GO
select ArchiveId, ScheduleId, Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4 
from TempArchive
GO
```

Returns:

```
ArchiveId   ScheduleId  Value1     Value2     Value3     Value4
----------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
1           2           1          2          3          4

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Keep in mind that with a lot of data, it's going to take a long time when you first add those computed columns.  I'd recommend testing it before putting it into production.  It will also increase the size of your table.

Comment: Added to answer... it was a bit more complicated to implement than expected.  :)

Comment: I'm going to try this out this morning but i suspect if inserting the data slows things down too much i will have to look at other options as we are adding lots of records from a machinery sensor logging application.

Also i will have to think about how to deal with the number of Value elements being different between scheduleId's (the number is the same for a single scheduleId but will differ between different scheduleId's

i will update the question to clarify.